# Suggestion on Input selector

Tags: integrated-circuit, relay, switching

I am working on a design where  I have 2 digital signals one is TX while other is RX. and at the output both are connected to same connection. This means my output is bi-directional. I am looking for a switch type of electrical circuit or IC which can connect one input(TX) to the output and keep other input(RX) unconnected. There is no possibility that both inputs have signals together.

TX and RX are 200mVpp. they are already on seperate signal line. But when they go to chip only one can go at once. I thought of using a select signal but as TX and RX are in Vpp and no other signal can determine when its transmitting or when its receiving.

Comment: Search for multiplexers.

Comment: TX and RX are 200mVpp. they are already on seperate signal line. but when they go to chip only one can go at once. I thought of using a select signal but as TX and RX are in Vpp and no other signal can determine when its transmitting or when its receiving

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are going about this the wrong way.  If TX and RX are connected, then you don't have TX and RX, you have a single signal.  Some common ways of dealing with this:

Use a line driver with output enable.  The higher level protocol then guarantees that only one node is driving the bus at the same time.  RS-485 is a example of this, in this case using a differential pair for the signal.

The bus passively floats to one level, and nodes only ever drive it to the other level.  IIC and CAN are examples of this, where IIC is single ended and CAN differential.

Each node drives and receives with a carefully controlled impedance.  If done right, two nodes can use the same line transmitting to the other simultaneously.  Old style analog telephone is a example of this.